# Erro no método DELETE, para excluir um dado de uma tabela

Tags: java, jsp, método, delete

Estou tentando fazer um método para deletar uma entrada de uma table com Java e `jsp`, mas está dando erro 405. Vou anexar os códigos.

ProdutoDao.java:

```
public void remove(Produto produto) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(busca(produto));
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}

public Produto busca(Produto produto) {
    return em.find(Produto.class, produto.getId());
}
```

ProdutoController.java:

```
@Delete
public void remove(Produto produto){
    dao.remove(produto);
    result.redirectTo(this).lista();
}
```

lista.jsp:

```html
<div class="row">
    <form action="<c:url value='/produto/remove'/>" method="DELETE">
        <div class="col s4">
            REMOVER PELO ID:<input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 right">
            <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large right" value="REMOVER"></input>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

E o erro que aparece é o seguinte:

> HTTP Status [405] – [Method Not Allowed]
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Description The method received in the request-line is known by the
>   origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método está certo. O erro estava na form do JSP. O correto é o seguinte:

```html
<form action="<c:url value='/produto/remove?id=${produto.id}'/>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
    <div class="col s4 right">
        <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-small right" value="REMOVER"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Aí passei o botão ao lado da linha na tabela, assim ele pegava o id automático. Mais pra frente posso fazer um input text para passar o id para remover, mas a princípio vou deixar assim.

Answer (score 0):

Qual o path do controller?
Pelo que eu vi tem que verificar se o @Path que está no controller está correto e o método delete está  certo. Tente usar @DELETE, fica mais fácil para ler.

Comment: O path é o padrao da convenção, mas ja descobri o erro, era só uma diferença de leitura do navegador em questao ao metodo delete