# Erro ao tentar excluir com metodo DELETE usando web service rest em Java

Tags: java, java-ee, rest, jdbc

Criei um Web Service REST em Java. Todas as operações estão funcionando menos a de DELETE que retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: print do erro 405]

Método HTTP DELETE:

```
@DELETE
@Path("excluir/{idpromocao}")
public void excluir(@PathParam("idpromocao") int idpromocao){    
    Promocao P = new Promocao();
    P.setIdpromocao(idpromocao);

    PromocaoOp promo = new PromocaoOp();
    P = promo.buscar(P);

    promo.remove(P);
}
```

Método de exclusão:

```
public void remove(Promocao promocao) {
    id_conexao = N.Conectar();

    String sql = "delete from promocao where idpromocao=?";

    try {


        stmt = id_conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, promocao.getIdpromocao());

        //executa
        stmt.execute();

        System.out.println("Excluido");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("ERRO ao excluir promoção - " + e);

    } finally {
        N.Desconectar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Acredito que deve ser duplicata disso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214147/132

Comment: Outro caso parecido: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220738/132

Answer (score 0):

Veja a primeira linha da sua figura:

[image: imagem]

Lá está escrito:

```
GET SolicitaçãoFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (405)
```

Observe que a primeira palavra é **`GET`**. Deveria estar escrito **`DELETE`**.

Ou seja, o código que está tentando chamar o seu serviço está usando o método HTTP errado.

Além disso, dê uma olhada [**nessa pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) para melhorar o código do seu JDBC.